# Retrieve app id of Synapse service principal and add as administrator to AAS using Bicep

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-managed-identity, azure-bicep

I'm deploying Azure services by using Bicep. The property 'identity type system assigned' creates an enterprise application/service principal with a name, object id and app id. This is required to be able to process Azure Analysis Services from a Synapse pipeline.

```
//Create Synapse Analytics
resource synapseAnalytics 'Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces@2021-06-01' = {
  name: synapse_name
  location: region
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    defaultDataLakeStorage: {
      filesystem: storage_account_fileshare_name
      resourceId: storageAccount.id
      accountUrl: storage_account_url
      createManagedPrivateEndpoint: true
    }
    managedVirtualNetwork: 'default'
    publicNetworkAccess: 'Enabled'
    managedResourceGroupName: synapse_workspace_name
    azureADOnlyAuthentication: false
    cspWorkspaceAdminProperties: {
      initialWorkspaceAdminObjectId: xxxx
    }
  }
  dependsOn: [
    storageAccountFileshare
  ]
}
```

I need to retrieve the app id of the created resource to add to Azure Analysis Service as an administrator.

```
resource analysisServices 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices/servers@2017-08-01' = {
  name: anaylsis_services_name
  location: region
  sku: {
    name: 'B1'
    tier: 'Basic'
    capacity: 1
  }
  properties: {
    asAdministrators: {
      members: [
        'obj:xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx@xxxxx-xxx-xxxxx-xxxxx'
        'app:{GET APP ID OF SYNAPSE}' <------------------
      ]
    }
    managedMode: 1
  }
}
```

How can I access the app id in my Bicep code?

I'm able to retrieve the app id by using a powershell command. Unfortunately this command needs an object id which I'm not able to retrieve by using powershell commands.

```
az ad sp show --id {object-id} --query appId
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a system-assigned identity, you can't get the appId directly from bicep.
But you could output the `principalId`

```bicep
//Create Synapse Analytics
resource synapseAnalytics 'Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces@2021-06-01' = {
  name: synapse_name
  ...
}

// return the principalId to query the appId
output principalId string = synapseAnalytics.identity.principalId
```

You can then use the principalId to get the appId

```
az ad sp show --id <principalId from bicep> --query appId
```

Using a user-assigned identity, you would be able to do it all in bicep:

```bicep
// Create a user identity for synapse
resource userAssignedIdentity 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities@2018-11-30' = {
  name: userAssignedIdentityName
  location: region
}

//Create Synapse Analytics
resource synapseAnalytics 'Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces@2021-06-01' = {
  name: synapse_name
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned,UserAssigned'
    userAssignedIdentities: {
      // assign the managed identity
      '${userAssignedIdentity.id}': {}
    }
  }
  ...
}

// Create the analysis service
resource analysisServices 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices/servers@2017-08-01' = {
  name: anaylsis_services_name
  ...
  properties: {
    asAdministrators: {
      members: [
        ...
        // Set app id and tenantid as per documentation
        'app:${userAssignedIdentity.properties.clientId}@${userAssignedIdentity.properties.tenantId}' 
      ]
    }
    ...
  }
}
```